# How to Remove the first characters that same as in another textbox : vb6

Tags: textbox, vb6

i have 2 textboxs, text1 and text2

i want to remove the first characters in text1 that same as in text2

```
text1 = 1234

text2 = 12
```

Result

```
text1 = 34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to say that you have three textboxes and they have the values:

```
Text1.Text = "1234"
Text2.Text = "12"
```

and you want Text3 to contain the remaining text of Text1 that is not common in Text2: then this is what you need to do:

```
Text1.Text = "1234"
Text2.Text = "12"
Text3.Text = Mid(Text1.Text, InStr(Text1.Text, Text2.Text) + Len(Text2.Text))
'The value in Text3.Text will be "34"
```

Otherwise, if you want the Result to be stored into Text1 again, just assign the result to Text1 instead of Text3

```
Text1.Text = Mid(Text1.Text, InStr(Text1.Text, Text2.Text) + Len(Text2.Text))
'The value in Text1.Text will be replaced with "34"
```

Comment: I don't believe he meant 3 textboxes since he **explicitly** states 2, your method will work, just assign the result of your Mid Function to Textbox1

Comment: i want the result be put in text1 and this is working , or may be put in text3 , any textbox is good , thanks